# How to change max concurrent runs of Glue Jobs run in parallel from an AWS Step Function Map?

Tags: amazon-web-services, concurrency, terraform, aws-glue, aws-step-functions

I have a Step Function with a Map to run 5 parallel Glue Jobs with custom arguments, something like this:

```
"Run Glue Jobs": {
  "Type": "Map",
  "MaxConcurrency": 5,
  "ItemsPath": "$.payload",
  "Iterator": {
    "StartAt": "Run Generic Glue Job",
    "States": {
      "Run Generic Glue Job": {
        "Type": "Task",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
        "Parameters": {
          "JobName": "GlueJobName",
          "Arguments": {
            "--target_bucket": "target-bucket",
            "--target_path": "dir1/dir2/",
            "--job-language": "python",
            "--job-bookmark-option": "job-bookmark-disable",
            "--TempDir": "s3://temp-bucket/tmp-glue",
            "--continuous-log-logGroup": "gluecloudwatch",
            "--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log": "true",
            "--enable-continuous-log-filter": "true",
            "--enable-metrics": "",
            "--kmskeyid": "arn:aws:kms:region:12345678901:alias/glue-kms-key"
          }
        },
        "End": true
      }
    }
  },
  "Next": "Finish"
```

When I run this stage of the step function, it catches errors, namely: Glue.ConcurrentRunsExceededException
Is there a way to pass a parameter somewhere like MaxConcurrentRuns:5 (ExecutionProperty) so I can run up to 5 jobs simultaneously ? I can't find anywhere a way to do that. Only this unrelated resource: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glue/create-job.html

I can only do that manually Editing the job in the GUI, but I need to create everything from scratch in Terraform so I need to also enable 5 MaxConcurrentRuns from a written source. Any tips? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We can't set Glue Max Concurrent Runs from Step Functions. If Step function Map is run with `MaxConcurrency` 5, we need to create/update glue job max concurrent runs to minimum 5 as well.

When we create Glue Job from AWS CLI, we can pass `MaxConcurrentRuns` as ExecutionProperty.MaxConcurrentRuns

Here is a sample json

```
 {
    "Name": "my-glue-job",
    "Role": "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:role/glue_etl_service_role",
    "ExecutionProperty": {
        "MaxConcurrentRuns": 5
    },
    "Command": {
        "Name": "glueetl",
        "ScriptLocation": "s3://temp-sandbox/code/scripts/MyGlueScript.scala",
        "PythonVersion": "3"
    },
    "DefaultArguments": {
        "--TempDir": "s3://aws-glue-temporary-111122223333-us-east-1/admin",
        "--class": "com.mycompany.corp.MainClass",
        "--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log": "true",
        "--enable-metrics": "",
        "--enable-spark-ui": "true",
        "--extra-jars": "s3://temp-sandbox/code/jars/MyExtraJar.jar",
        "--job-bookmark-option": "job-bookmark-disable",
        "--job-language": "scala",
        "--spark-event-logs-path": "s3://aws-glue-assets-111122223333-us-east-1/sparkHistoryLogs/"
    },
    "MaxRetries": 0,
    "Timeout": 2880,
    "WorkerType": "G.1X",
    "NumberOfWorkers": 10,
    "GlueVersion": "2.0"
}
```

with cli

```
aws glue create-job --cli-input-json file://myFolder/glue_job_props.json
```

Answer (score 1):

So apparently there's a way to specify max concurrent runs right from Terraform in a resource "aws_glue_job", it's the following:

```
execution_property {
    max_concurrent_runs = 5
}
```

It's probably solved this way. I'll try to use that.